# Can one deduce Gelfand Duality from Isbell Duality?

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems, gelfand-duality

I was reading about [Isbell Duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+duality) in nLab.

It gives an example of how we have an adjunction from $TAlg$ to presheaves.

But it is not clear to me how one can deduce the [Gelfand Duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gelfand+duality) from this.